# How to deal with lag of width size between TextView and Layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

**EDITED**
I have a `TextView`. I am getting the `TextView` width programmatically and then setting it to the **width** of my `Layout`. Say,  the **width** of my `TextView` is 60, then i apply it to my `Layout` using `myLayout.getLayoutParams().width`. Why there is a lag of width for the `Layout` and for the `TextView` i.e. the layout shows different width on screen , not equal to that one of my `TextView`.

In short, **60** width for `TextView` is different from **60** width of `Layout`.

I am getting the width of `TextView` like this :

```
int textWidth = getTextWidth(text,(int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, editText.getTextSize(), getResources().getDisplayMetrics()), null);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you stuffing your logic programmatically. Simply use `wrap_content` in your layout, and it will do all the logic that you are doing in you **java** class.

Change the **width** of your layout to `android:layout_width = "wrap_content"`

Comment: Yes, finally got my solution. thnx @Ali.